# How do I set return type to React.StatelessComponent?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is working:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default (props: any): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <h1>{props.children}</h1>
  )
}
```

And this is throwing an error:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default (props: any): React.StatelessComponent => {
  return (
    <h1>{props.children}</h1>
  )
}
```

How do I set the return type to `React.StatelessComponent`?

Comment: What are you using? Flow? Typescript?

Comment: updated with typescript tag

Comment: Almost wrote my answer assuming flow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use default export, its an antipattern.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const MyComponent: React.StatelessComponent = (props) => <h1>{props.children}</h1>
```

Note that I also removed `return` keyword and curly braces, because its an arrow function and it does not do anything other than returning JSX

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to split the component and its export:

```
const MyComp: SFC<{}> = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <h1>{props.children}</h1>
  )
}

export default MyComp
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to `export` and assign a type in the same statement without using `as`. [This fork of your example](https://codesandbox.io/s/p98jovl9q7) passes linting

Comment: Yeah, I realized that and edited my answer just before your comment. :).

Answer (score 0):

To declare and cast in the same statement - you're probably going to have to set the type of your component using `as`.

See below for a practical example.

```
// Types.
type Props = any

// Export.
export default (props => 
  <h1>{props.children}</h1>
) as React.StatelessComponent<Props>
```

Comment: Wrapping the whole component in parens and using the `as` operator is a neat trick. Although, readability wise, I don't how this would look for slightly bigger SFCs.

Comment: Thanks. It tends to make more sense when avoiding [name collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_collision). I find it most useful when amalgamating [emotion components](https://emotion.sh/) where parts might logically have similar/identical names to the whole @Mrchief